# PlayerForm.is_valid always false but player is still saving

Tags: python, html, django

I designed a leaderboard app where there are players and games.

When you register, it creates a Django user and creates a `Player` object that is associated with the user. When I register, if `PlayerForm.is_valid` is `True`, the user and player is created where `PlayerForm(UserCreationForm)` and it renders a the `elosearch.html`, otherwise, it returns to the `register.html`.

I can see that the player and user is being created but when I submit the request it is rendering `register.html` rather than `elosearch.html`. How is it rendering the wrong view if `is_valid` produces `True` and if it doesn't, why are the player and user saving? I created my own html form so I don't actually need to pass the form to the template (args is not used)

PlayerForm

```
class PlayerForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(PlayerForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        user.password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        new_player = Player(name=str(user.username), user=user)

        if commit:
            user.save()
            new_player.save()

        return user
```

Register View

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PlayerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'elousers/elosearch.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'elousers/register.html')
    else:
        form = PlayerForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'elousers/register.html', args)
```

I can see that the player and user is being created but when I submit the request it is rendering `register.html` rather than `elosearch.html`.

Comment: @markwalker_ are you able to aid in any tips or were you just adjusting the format?

Comment: Does `new_player.save()` throw an error?

Comment: Yes it was throwing the error so I removed it and now it is all working and the players are being added to the database so I think its all good? not sure if its a problem that I am not explicitly saving the player